# How do I recover my download from Microsoft File Transfer Manager?

Tags: internet-explorer, download-manager, file-download

Last night I downloaded Visio 2013 Preview using the highly dubious MS File Transfer Manager* and when I checked this morning, the download had completed, but was marked as suspended, because FTM cannot rename the temporary file.

It was downloading to C:, so maybe it's permissions problem, although I am running as admin.

I was advised to manually rename the temp file, but couldn't locate it via a quick Windows Explorer search. I was also advised to start FTM As Admin, but I couldn't find where to start it. When I started IE as admin, and tried to resume to the download, FTM summarily decided to restart the download.

My patience will not survive a second such debacle, so when my second download is down, and this happens again, what can I do?

**Why must they insist on their download manager, and if they must, why not stick with Akamai?*

Comment: I'm of the opinion that the original file is gone. When it is downloading again, use Process Monitor from SysInternals to see where it is writing the file to, and use that as a starting point for renaming the file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the file you were downloading may have been too big, where you may have been trying to store a file in excess of 4Gig on a FAT32 file system or something. That's probably not the case if you're using a modern version of Windows. But it's still something to think about since a lot of attached storage devices and even other partitions still use FAT32.

Or it could be that you are out of hard drive space!!! So is it possible that the free space where you downloaded this file doesn't have at least twice the free space of the file? I can't say, but that would be the first place I'd be looking. Otherwise, I'd be looking at power settings and seeing if maybe your computer didn't just decide to go to sleep or into hibernation mode before it was done downloading - or maybe even shut down!

I doubt the file permissions are the problem since you should still be able to download if the server is able to send. Then again, are you sure an antivirus program isn't causing a problem?! Remember, most AV clients will do a quick scan to see if there isn't a known bad signature or something. So this could be what's happening. Your AV client may have mistaken that file as having a virus and may have even quarantined it. (Then again, it may actually have a virus too!)

Those things aside, you may want to be looking at your download client. I can't help much there since I don't use external FTP clients or allow torrents (which are two other huge things you may want to (re)consider). But once you start downloading with a particular client then you're pretty much at it's mercy until it's all done. So don't restart your download. Try resuming if that happens again.

Of course, there's always the possibility that the server is simply going down for maintenance or something when you're in the middle of this download. So if that's the case then there's really nothing wrong on your end. You may want to ask the site operator(s) or maybe try getting this file from a different mirror (if that's an option).

Hope it helps.

Comment: The file is around 400MB, and I have 400GB free on a new Windows 7 box. I didn't choose the download client, MS chose it for me, which is part of the problem. I have managed to start the download now outside of that client and use another one, but my question wasn't how to download the file, but how to recover from the abortion caused by the MS FTM. Thanks for the suggestions anyway.